# UIView subclass won't update

Tags: iphone, uiview, frame, cgrect

I have a custom uiview that i am trying to update the frame size. I do it like this in a method once it is clicked. The method is called, and the frame value changes, however on the screen nothing happens!  What I think is happening is the subclass is not being redrawn or updated

```
- (void)resizeWithTag:(int)tag wasTouched:(BOOL)touched
{
    if (!touched) {

        GameBox *box = (GameBox *)[self.view viewWithTag:40];
        CGRect frame = box.frame;
        frame.origin.x += 30;
        box.frame = frame;
        [[self.view viewWithTag:40] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 73)];
        [box layoutSubviews];
        NSLog(@"%f", box.frame.origin.x);
        markButton.enabled = NO;
        guessButton.enabled = NO;
        [self.view reloadInputViews];

        NSLog(@"The action bar should now be hidden");
    }
    else if (touched) {
        guessButton.enabled = YES;
        markButton.enabled = YES;
        [self.view reloadInputViews];
        NSLog(@"The action bar should now be visible");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, this is a custom UIView you method is in correct? Thus `self.view` makes no sense. If it is a `UIViewController`, try calling `viewDidLoad` again. If it is actually UIView, try this `[self setNeedsDisplay]`